# How to access header files in project ROOT directory in Xcode, header file not found

Tags: xcode, header-files

I've been trying to make a framework which uses .h header files. So I followed a tutorial where simply a few header files. (Tutorial link : https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial )
The problem I face is that I can't access header files of another directory in the .h files of the same framework.

The steps I did were : I did the same and copied header files(not just their references) to the base framework's folder as shown. I also, added another folder(itpp) which also contains some more header files.

[image]
**As you can see, the trigger.h file contains code, #include< itpp/itbase.h >**

After this, I added the header files of the base folder in the public directory.  The header files from itpp folder were not added there when I copied the "itpp" directory. Also, I don't want the framework to give direct access to the itpp header files.

[image]

Now I successfully build the framework. And copy the framework file(after showing in finder to an accessible place. Then I embed the framework I built and also, in the .mm file successfully write the following line of code : #include < BPSK/trigger.h > [image]

But the **error** I encounter is that **< itpp/itbase.h >** cannot be found ,something I haven't been able to resolve. I went through many links which were close to what I wanted but didn't help me with this scenario.
I'm posting the links as well:

Helping Xcode fine library header - https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/01/helping-xcode-find-library-headers/

How to create Custom iOS Framework with resources like images, plist, etc. -
http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-create-custom-ios-framework-with.html

I even tried adding header files directory to the header search fields but it didn't work.
*How can I use the header files in itpp folder in .h files that are accessible by the custom framework being built.*